# Engine is warm but interior blows cold air until Throttle is engaged? Blows hot till next cold start

Tags: heater, heater-blower

We have a 2003 Toyota 4Runner with the V8.

The temperature here has been below -20c many times so far this year.
About a week ago my wife noticed that her 4runner is not warm inside when using her remote start.  I drove this weekend and the remote starter works fine, engine temperature rises to normal running levels but the heater will not blow warm air until we enter the vehicle and step on the gas peddle. 
Once we do this the heat works just fine until the next time we cold start the vehicle. 
We have since topped up the antifreeze and this has not solved the problem.

Any assistance here would be appreciated.

Comment: @GdD OP says topping up the antifreeze has *not* solved the problem. Not sure what else in the question you might be referring to.

Comment: I'd usually think weak vacuum isn't operating the blend door actuators, but the 4runner uses electric servos.

Comment: Does the car have an electric pump to circulate water to the heater matrix?  If so, maybe this pump is not working anymore.

Comment: @HandyHowie if the pump wasn't working I would not expect to have *any* heat, yet they say it works fine once the idle has been bumped up.

Comment: @ChristopherHunter  The electric pump is often for the times when the mechanical pump isn't providing enough circulation like at idle. Once the mechanical pump is running at normal speed, there is enough circulation to keep the heater working.

Comment: @HandyHoiwie. Interesting, because I have a 2000 Tacoma with the exact same issue. However I just thought it was "normal", and heat wouldn't start circulating until the engine had warmed up  for a few minutes by being driven.